# How do I maintain two different sessions using shared preferences for two users (driver and rider) in the same application?

Tags: android

How do I maintain two different sessions using shared preferences for two users (driver and rider) in the same Android application? I have two activities one for rider and the other one is for driver but when i login as a driver and then close the app and reopen it then it will navigate me on rider's module.

Share preference class:

```java
public class PrefManager {

    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "logginSession";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String KEY_IS_WAITING_FOR_SMS = "IsWaitingForSms";
    private static final String KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER = "mobile_number";
    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN = "isLoggedIn";
    private static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String USER_TYPE = "mobile";

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    /**
     * Set the Login Status
     * @param context
     * @param loggedIn
     */
    public static void setLoggedIn(Context context, boolean loggedIn){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(context).edit();
        editor.putBoolean(LOGGED_IN_PREF, loggedIn);
        editor.apply();
    }

    /**
     * Get the Login Status
     * @param context
     * @return boolean: login status
     */
    public static boolean getLoggedStatus(Context context) {
        return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(LOGGED_IN_PREF, false);
    }

    public void setIsWaitingForSms(boolean isWaiting) {
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_WAITING_FOR_SMS, isWaiting);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isWaitingForSms() {
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_WAITING_FOR_SMS, false);
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        editor.putString(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, mobileNumber);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return pref.getString(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, null);
    }

    public void createLogin(String mobile) {
        editor.putString(KEY_MOBILE, mobile);
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
    }

    public  void clearSession() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> profile = new HashMap<>();

        profile.put("userID", pref.getString(KEY_MOBILE, null));
        profile.put("sessionID", pref.getString(KEY_MOBILE, null));
        profile.put("mobile", pref.getString(KEY_MOBILE, null));
        return profile;
    }

    // ...
```

In rider's verification Activity: when I retrieve otp from Api I use .set loggedin method from shared preference class:

```
    // Parsing json object response
    // response will be a json object
    boolean error = responseObj.getBoolean("error");
    String message = responseObj.getString("message");
    if (!error) {
        PrefManager.setLoggedIn(getApplicationContext(), true);
    }

}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}) { ... }
```

And in driver,s Verification I do the same as rider's verification (above scenario).

Comment: What would help: is it on the same device? can you post simplified version of what was attempted to date? What is the exact problem you're fixing (is it default activity after login, is it an issue with storing data in shared prefs)?

Comment: sure! wait i am posting some code.

Comment: @AivarasPrudnikovas i have a single module in my app but two different functionality. First one is login as rider and the other one is login as a driver both user have different login screens and different activities/classes. rider login is open by default but when i login as a driver it takes my to driver,s flow which is ok but when i reopen app it will navigate me to rider's screen which is not ok. i use shared preference class for both modules. i also try two different shared prefence classes but it will not make sense to use two classes

Comment: use this [Link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-maintain-two-different-sessions-using-shared-preferences-for-two-users-in-the-same-Android-application). it might help you

Comment: @Alfaizkhan thanks buddy. i already read this this is for single user

Comment: In your example we see how value is stored by using `setLoggedIn`, but it is still not clear how you open an Activity after that setting. Are you using `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` or just `startActivity(intent)` and how you distinguish between _driver_ and _rider_ in that action?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because I don't know what you are doing exactly I will guess.
Probably you check in the beginning if you have saved data for a rider and if this is true, you open rider. I can think of two solutions.
 1. delete Sharedpreferences for rider when you login as driver and vice versa.
 2. If you want to maintain both data you need to add some kind of key which one you want to open on app start. `prefs.editor.put("activeUser", "driver").apply()`. Than on App start you need to check if activeUser is "driver" or "rider" and open the corresponding Activity.

Comment: i already try that scenario to clear preference in drivers verification but result was same.

Comment: @ShahzaibSohaib
If I get it right it should be like this: You login as Rider and save your data in SharedPrefs. Than you login as driver and save that data in other SharedPrefs. How are you deciding which one to show? If driver is available in SharedPrefs it should always show driver? If it is like that, you need to do the check if Driver is logged in Splash Activity if so, open DriverActivity. It doesn't help you if you do the check in Driver/riders Activity because it's too late to do it there (Riders Activity is already active). Therefore check in your SplashActivity.

Comment: @ShahzaibSohaib also make sure that your SplashActivity is set as your launcher Activity in Manifest. You also need to add a function to your SharedPrefs -> `public void setUserType(String userType)` and right after `PrefManager.setLoggedIn(getApplicationContext(), true);`,you need to call `PrefManager.setUserType("driver")` (replace "driver" for "rider" if you are logging in as rider). In SplashActivity in Oncreate method you check `if(PrefManager.getUserType() == "driver"){ //open driver Activity}
else if(PrefManager.getUserType() == "rider") {//open rider Activity}
else{ //open default} `

Comment: i have a login screen which contains a button to login as a driver both have different verification activities where driver/ rider can enter otp. otp contains user and session id. and i store mobile number in preferences but i think you scenario will help me to solve this issue

Comment: i don't have any splash where can i evaluate this i have two different login activities and also two different verification activities

Comment: You can add a SplashActivity easily it should just show your App logo for example. But if you don't want to add it, then you need to do the check in your Launcheractivity. If your LoginActivity is the launcher Activity just check there in the onCreate method which usertype you are handling and depending on the result open the correct Activity.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. You helped me alot. i am really very thankful to you. <3

Answer (score 1):

In you current implementation, You have to check in RiderLoginActivity's **onCreate** whether user **isLoggedIn** or not and what is the **type** of the user to move next.

Based on that you have bellow options:

```
if(isLoggedIn) {
    if(type == "driver")
        //navigate to driver module
    else
        //navigate to rider module
}
```

But this is not the best practice. You should have one **welcome screen/ Splash Screen** and make this decision there. In that case you have to implement else like this.

```
else
    //navigate to RiderLoginActivity
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: rider login activity and there is a button who navigates user to driver login activity

Answer (score 0):

Make the different preference for both app.then you can access both data for this

Comment: i already try this but it dosent work. the error remain same.

Comment: private static final String PREF_NAME1 = "driver";
private static final String PREF_NAME2 = "rider";

make two preference and also initialize both different and also set make different method .so this way possible and onlogout time clear session.

Comment: but where can i evaluate the target activity to launch for example for rider it goes to rider activity and for driver it goes to driver activity

Comment: from splash screen you have to decide for that..and first time you choose any one then after you go.

Comment: i dont have a splash screen in my app

Comment: riderlogin activity and there is button who navigate user to driver login screen

Comment: right rider login to rider main activity and same for driver